# What is the file container in Progress Developer Studio?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to write a .p file in OpenEdge - Progress Developer Studio. So for that, I just go the File > New > ABL Procedure.

When the 'New ABL Procedure' pop up, a Container field is showing. I am very new to write a .p code in Progress 4GL. I need to know what file is needed in this file container field.

Screenshot attached for reference.
[OpenEdgeDeveloperStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fepvH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the browse button, you need to choose the project/folder that shpuld contain the new file.

But you need to create an OpenEdge Project using the New project wizard first.

Comment: Thanks, it works. After creating a new project, I can see that folder that should contain the new .p file.

Answer (score 0):

Container field should be assigned to a project name. To work with Progress Developer Studio, you need to create a project before creating a "ABL Procedure". For more information on creating a project, please check this [link](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/pdsoe/creating-a-new-openedge-project.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project first, your container should be assigned automatically. 
If your ".p" placed in a folder, your container will be

```
\[projectname]\[foldername]
```

**without bracket [ ]**

[image]

Simply right click on Project or folder > New > ABL Procedure. It will be assigned automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, create an OpenEdge project.
2. Try to create an ABL Procedure.
3. Example: Test is Project(Container) then try to create a new ABL procedure

[image]